# For loop not being called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason, by for loop is not being called. I'm using node.js.

```
console.log("Main Body Called!");

for (var i = 0; i < invitemessages.count; i++) {
    console.log("For Loop Called!");
    if (invitemessages[i].content.startsWith(message.author.id)) {
        msg = invitemessages[i].content;
}

console.log("After for loop called!")
```

In my console I get `Main Body Called!` and `After for loop called!` but not `For Loop Called!`.

I've got no idea why the `for` loop isn't being called. The length of `invitemessages` is not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think count property is giving you undefined. Try to console log it. Instead of that use length property.

```
await channel.fetchMessages().then((collection) => {
        invitemessages = collection.array();
        for (var i = 0; i < invitemessages.length; i++) {
        console.log("For Loop Called!");
        if (invitemessages[i].content.startsWith(message.author.id)) {
            msg = invitemessages[i].content;
        }
    }
    });
```